# Call function from arbitrary souce .cpp file using the file name as a string

Tags: c++, function, macros

I am going through coding problems online, and I thought of a system that could make testing really efficient. My plan is to

1. give each problem a distinct .cpp file with one function that solves the problem and outputs the results to a .txt file
2. create a .cpp file with a main function that takes 2 command line arguments: a string the file name for the problem I am currently solving and a string for the file name of the test case to be used for the problem.

The main function first creates a FILE* to store the test case and another FILE* to create an empty output file. Then, it calls the function from the problem .cpp file specified in the command line.

The function prototype for each problem file looks like this:

static void Problem(FILE* test_case, FILE* output);

The idea is to pass in the test case to a specific problem and have the "Problem" function write the results into an output text file.

I've succeeded in running test cases for a specific problem and getting unique output files for each run.

However, my current issue is enabling the main function to use the .cpp file name as an argument. It seems there is no direct way in C++ to call a function from a file using only the file name. I know that the preprocessor parses .cpp files and turns function names into function pointers. Is there a way I can do this at runtime? In other words, can I stream the .cpp file, search for the line that matches my function prototype, and return a pointer to that function? Is there some sort of macro I could use to cue the preprocessor to associate a file's name with its function?

From my search for answers thus far, the simplest solution seems to be to create a map that matches function name to function. This seems tedious and inelegant to me. I figure I might as well just change the function call manually in my main file every time I switch problems, instead of setting the name of the file in the command line. I prefer not to do either.

Comment: You can actually do this, but it means compiling the source code to a loadable library, loading the library, calling the function and then saving the result.  It involves dynamically linking in the library into the entire app to be tested and managing security concerns so that you don't open your testable app to attacks.

It's one of those problems that looks superficially easy but has layers and layers of added complexity.  If you want to pursue it anyway I suggest coursework in operating systems.

Comment: Since you functions are static, they will not be able to be called directly from any program. Even if they are linked in.

Comment: There is [Boost.DLL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_dll.html), which would allow you to create your test cases as "plugins" with a common interface. These test case plugins could then be dynamically loaded by the main application. From the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html) it looks fairly easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

In Standard C++ there is no direct means of doing this. However, most implementations  provide facilities for loading libraries, and calling named functions from those libraries, at run-time. For example, under Windows, you can call LoadLibrary to load a named DLL, and then call GetProcAddress to get a pointer to a named callable (C) function. Other operating systems provide similar features. This is not as useful a feature as it may seem, and tends to result in fragile code.

Comment: Maybe [Boost.DLL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_dll.html) could be an alternative to directly calling LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to mitigate the "fragility" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your files could have a class that is static global. In its constructor pass it the function address. This constructor updates a global vector of functions that can get called by the main framework. If you need input and output file names, then add them to the constructor's argument list and vector.